# Selecting multiple scopes in advanced search page (FS4SP)

Tags: search-results, search-scope, fast-for-sharepoint, advanced-search

We have created a custom scopes using powershell scripts in new FAST Search in SP 2010 and all seems to be working fine while searching the keywords by selecting single scope.But when we select multiple scopes in advanced search page than zero results are returned for all combination of scopes.However results are returned when we search the keyword with combination of a scope (with entire web application as a rule) and a scope with entire sub site as a rule.

Scope - A : domain.test.com (As a Rule )

Scope - B : /domain.text.com/subsite1/ (As a Rule ) and Scope - c : /domain.text.com/subsite2/ (As a Rule )

results.aspx?k=4379&s=A --> Results are returned

results.aspx?k=4379&s=B --> Results are returned

results.aspx?k=4379&s=C --> Results are returned

**results.aspx?k=ALL(4379) (scope:"B" OR scope:"C") --> No Results are returned**

results.aspx?k=ALL(4379) (scope:"A" OR scope:"C") --> Results are returned

results.aspx?k=ALL(4379) (scope:"A" OR scope:"B") --> Results are returned

Basically results are returned only when both scopes has the content of same URL.

Can anyone help me to understand the concept behind this test cases?

Comment: Can anyone help me please!!

Comment: Please Help me !!

Comment: Can anyone help me on this.